# SPARQL for DBPedia: Undefined namespace prefix at 'dbpedia-owl' before

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Trying to re-use [this script](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?a%20?b%20?super%20%28?aLength%20%2B%20?bLength%20as%20?length%29%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%28?a%20?b%29%20%7B%20%28dbpedia-owl%3APerson%20dbpedia-owl%3ASportsTeam%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20select%20?a%20?super%20%28count%28?mid%29%20as%20?aLength%29%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?a%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%2A%20?mid%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?mid%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%2B%20?super%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20group%20by%20?a%20?super%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20select%20?b%20?super%20%28count%28?mid%29%20as%20?bLength%29%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?b%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%2A%20?mid%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?mid%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%2B%20?super%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20group%20by%20?b%20?super%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20?length%0D%0Alimit%201&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on) which used to work before, but it gives errors now:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 5: Undefined namespace prefix at 'dbpedia-owl' before 'dbpedia-owl:SportsTeam'
```

and the script itself:

```
select ?a ?b ?super (?aLength + ?bLength as ?length)
{
  values (?a ?b) { (dbpedia-owl:Person dbpedia-owl:SportsTeam) }

  { select ?a ?super (count(?mid) as ?aLength) { 
      ?a rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
      ?mid rdfs:subClassOf+ ?super .
    }
    group by ?a ?super
  }
  { select ?b ?super (count(?mid) as ?bLength) { 
      ?b rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
      ?mid rdfs:subClassOf+ ?super .
    }
    group by ?b ?super
  }
}
order by ?length
limit 1
```

Any ideas how to update it?

Comment: Prefix declarations have been changed for the DBpedia virtuoso instance. It's now `dbo` isntead of `dbpedia-owl`. In any case, to make a SPARQL query self-contained, always add the prefix declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace `dbpedia-owl` is not a [prefixed namespace in DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl).

If you know the URL for the namespace, you can use `PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <NAMESPACE_URL>` before the SPARQL query. But if you're looking for DBpedia resource definitions of `Person` and `SportsTeam`, then you should be using (perhaps) `dbo` instead of `dbpedia-owl`.

Comment: Cool thanks. Actually it is "dbo". If you fix it, id accept your answer.

Answer (score 5):

`dbpedia-owl:` is not currently a [predefined namespace prefix on DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl), though it once was.  It has been replaced by `dbo:`.

As things stand, you can either change all instances of `dbpedia-owl:` in your queries to `dbo:`, or add this to the start of your queries --

```
PREFIX  dbpedia-owl:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
```

The latter is recommended.

For best results, you should ***always include `PREFIX` declarations in your SPARQL***, instead of relying on such server-side predefinitions.  This avoids any problems if namespace predefinitions are removed (as in this case) or changed to new URLs, which could have unpredictable effect on your query results.